# Are soft-clipped bases used for variant calling in samtools + bcftools?

Tags: sam, samtools

If there are soft clipped base pairs specified in the CIGAR string for a read in a SAM/BAM file, will these be used for variant calling in a [samtools](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools.html) + [bcftools](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bcftools.html) workflow?

The [GATK HaplotypeCaller](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/tooldocs/current/org_broadinstitute_gatk_tools_walkers_haplotypecaller_HaplotypeCaller.php), for example, has an explicit option `--dontUseSoftClippedBases` for whether to use soft clipped bases. The samtools documentation does not mention clipped bases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, samtools (and therefore bcftools) does not use soft-clipped bases. You can quickly confirm this by using either `samtools depth` or `samtools mpileup` to look at a region with a soft-clipped alignment. You'll note that the soft-clipped region isn't used in the depth/pileup (both tools use the same underlying code, so it doesn't matter which you use). If you're curious, samtools ignores soft-clipped bases because it's based on making a per-base stack of alignments covering each position. In the BAM format, alignments are sorted and assigned to bins according to their start/end positions, which won't include soft-clipping. Consequently, when samtools is making the pileup it won't even see the alignments that would overlap a given base if soft-clipped bases were included.

This then sort of begs the question of what GATK's HaplotypeCaller is doing differently. There, regions in the genome are essentially assembled in a small de Bruijn graph, which allows for soft-clipped bases around indels to then be resolved, given that the graph would start/end a little-way on past each side of indels. This is also why you don't need to do indel realignment with the HaplotypeCaller (this was needed in the old UnifiedGenotyper).

**Edit**: For more details regarding the HaplotypeCaller, see [this nice page](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/article.php?id=4146) on GATK's website, which goes into much more detail than I did here.